# Autonomous Systems, Two First Order ODE's - phase portraits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have two questions. The first relates to stable/unstable nodes, where the eigenvalues of the system are either both negative or both positive. How do you know where to draw the trajectories. Which of the manifolds are tangent to the trajectories (which in such a case are parabolas) and which coincide with them. Here's an example:

[image]

[image]

What I don't understand in that example is 'The trajectories which start from the initial conditions away from the invariant manifolds...' (the last three lines. How have they managed to deduce the behaviour of the trajectories away from the initial conditions.

My second question is two do with identifying the direction of the trajectories in systems where the determinant is less than zero: $$\mathrm{tr}( A ) ^ 2 - 4 \det(A) < 0$$ (so complex eigenvalues). In such cases, you will either have a centre or a focus depending on the values of the real and imaginary parts, but how would you go about finding the direction of motion along those trajectories (ellipses or spirals)?

This is the first time I've seen this kind of maths, so if anyone has any pointers or words of wisdom, it would highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can see the direction of the flow field if you plot the slope field at a few points around the origin. for the first problem, the solutions approach the eigendirection corresponding the largest eigenvalue, here it is $2$ and the direction is $(1,-1)^T.$ the opposite happens as $t \to -\infty.$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand what you are saying, but I'd like to know the reason behind it? I mean how is it as t→∞ that leads to trajectories tending to y=-x and so on?

Comment: look at the limit of $\pmatrix{x\\y}e^{-2t}.$ what can you say about this limit?

Comment: well as t tends to infinity, (x y)^T e^(−2t) tends to (x y)^T

Comment: the limit is $c_2\pmatrix{1\\-1}$

Comment: I'm sorry if these seem like stupid questions but I'm still confused. I don't see how that fits in to: 'The trajectories which start from the initial conditions away from the invariant manifolds tend asymptotically for t > infinity, to be parallel to one of the manifolds y = -x, whereas close to
the origin they are tangent to another manifold y = x' ?

Comment: I take it solutions always approach/parallel to the eigendirection with the largest eigenvalue, and are tangential to the one with a lower eigenvalue?

Comment: here is another way to look at it. look at the $\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac y x$

Comment: Ohhh is that how they got the y=-x (sorry my rep isn't big enough to begin a chat)